# How do I Get rid of "MyFirstProject"

Tags: azure-devops

I have VS 2017 Pro and have a number of projects in the default path C:\Users\jjacobs\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\

I just started Team Source from my company MSDN subscription. I chose Team Services rather then GitHub. My last version control system was Visual Source Safe. VSTS is totally alien to me.

I have a worthless project in VSTS called MyFirstProject. How do I remove it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go to **https://{your-domain}.visualstudio.com/_settings/projects**, hover over the project you would like to delete, click the three dots that appear, then select *delete*.

Comment: Wonderful. Please mark my answer as correct so that others can view it in the future. @JonJacobs

Comment: @Jon Jacobs, Since this issue has been resolved, would you please mark the helpful solution as the answer? So it could help other community members who get the same issue. Have a nice day:)

Comment: I would have already marked this as the answer, but I see no way to do that.

Comment: @JonJacobs You should see a large check mark that you can click.